# ab test on simple load balanced node.js configuration fails

Tags: node.js, testing, connection, http-proxy

I am beggining to install and learn avout node.js and for this reason I am testing some basic configurations e during an AB test I get always a problem.

I have 4 instances of a very small node script started on the port: 8001, 8002, 8003 and 8004.
I have also a node script for load balancing with module http-proxy launched on port 80.

This is the code of load balancing script:

```
var arguments = process.argv.splice(2);
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//
// Addresses to use in the round robin proxy
//
var addresses = [
    {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8001
    },
    {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8002
    },
    {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8003
    },
    {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8004
    }
];

var i = 0;
httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
    proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, addresses[i]);

    i = (i + 1) % addresses.length;
}).listen(arguments[0] || 80);
```

And this is the code of script waiting on port 8001, 8002, 8003, 8004:

```
var http = require("http");
var port = process.argv[2];

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200);
  response.end("aGoodPower");
}).listen(port);
```

Then I launch the scripts in this way:

```
     1. open terminal
 2. get root credentials: su (password)
 3. launch scripts:
    node simpleServer.js 8001 &
    node simpleServer.js 8002 &
    node simpleServer.js 8003 &
    node simpleServer.js 8004 &
    node nodeHttpProxy.js &
 4. ab -n 100000 -c 100 http://127.0.0.1/
```

This test fails always between the 30.000 and 40.000 request with the error: apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)

I do not know why, and I cannot find an explication on the net.

I did the same test with a single simpleServer.js script and the test finished until 100.000 requests without problems.

Can anyone suggest me where is the problem?

Thank you very much
Elaidon

Comment: Check out this round robin approach from the `node-http-proxy` project. I believe you are running into issues with setting a global counter `i` and the method here is more straight forward with Array primitives https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/blob/master/examples/balancer/simple-balancer.js

Comment: Hi jibsales and thank you, but the problem is not solved. I used the script you said but as usual I obtain the following message:  ab -n 100000 -c 100 http://127.0.0.1/
 This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
 Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
 Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

 Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
 Completed 10000 requests
 Completed 20000 requests
 Completed 30000 requests
 apr_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
 Total of 33000 requests completed